# Custom compound view and .findViewById()

Tags: android, android-custom-view, layout-inflater, custom-view, findviewbyid

I am really worried about the `.findViewById()` method and its use in a custom compound view creation. I am not sure about the exact place that it is guaranteed that it will never return `null`.

Let's say I have this custom compound view and that it is added to some `.xml` like this:

```
<com.app.path.TwoButtonsView
            android:id="@+id/ok_cancel_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`two_buttons_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

`TwoButtonsView.java`

```
public class TwoButtonsView extends LinearLayout {

    // views
    private TextView mFirstButtonView;
    private TextView mSecondButtonView;

    public TwoButtonsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public TwoButtonsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public TwoButtonsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TwoButtonsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_buttons_view, this);

        // retrieve views
        mFirstButtonView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.first_button); // is there a chance it will return null?
        mSecondButtonView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.second_button); // is there a chance it will return null?
    }
}
```

---

My question is: is there any chance that `.findViewById(RESOURCE_ID)` will return `null` right after calling `inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_buttons_view, this);`, or should I call my `init()` method on `onFinishInflate()` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: is there any chance that .findViewById(RESOURCE_ID)
>   will return null right after calling
>   inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_buttons_view, this)

No, there is not, as long as the views you are looking for are in the layout and you explicitly added to the view's hierarchy. In the end, `findViewById` loops on `View[]`, filled up by `addView`.

A small note about

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_buttons_view, this);
```

`ViewGroup` has the static method `inflate`, so you don't need to retrieve the `inflater` calling `getSystemService`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Blackbelt!

Could you explain me what is the purpose of `onFinishInflate()` then, please?

Comment: it is a callback that gets call when all the children declared in the layout have been added. In your case, you are adding manually

Comment: Thanks again for the answer :D. One final question: you said that I added them manually, but what is the other way to add them "not manually"? I could not think of any =/

Comment: when you declare those in the xml. Android inflates them and add it for you

Comment: Oh, but this custom view were added through xml (in another layout), and so its children (in its xml).

Comment: not thy are not. You are retrieving the inflater, and inflating the layout manually and asking it to add it.